# Dynamic web forms using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a convention website for agents using VS 2010. The agents can bring up to 6 guests if they want. I am creating a form to store basic info on these guests. Instead of creating six forms with the same repeated info, I want to use the same form up to six times. I want to store the info on session variables before calling a stored procedure to insert them in the database.

Can you help?

Comment: This question is way to broad to be answered here. Please try to re-phrase, including specifics on what you need to know and what you have tried.

Comment: yes we can help.  have you created your form?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're collecting (differentiated from storing) this registration info on an ASP site. You should just be able to pass the info back on a GET or POST from the webform, which is then retrieved and parsed in the code-behind, and then the individual pieces of information passed to a stored proc to update the database.

Your question was a little vague, so I do not know what your database schema is right now, but you will at least need a registration information table, and a main registrant table which ties to the former table on a one to many basis. Beyond this, I cannot help without more details...i.e. what do you have besides what you wrote in your question.

Comment: i am calling a SP using ado.net to insert the data